# CSS3 animation doesn't work in Chrome/IE10 but works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, animation, internet-explorer-10

i want to create an instagram wall so i set jquery nested for rendering the pictures and i want an automatic scroll until bottom.
This code works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE10+.
I don't know what's wrong about it. I use LESS.
Thanks for helping

```
.animation(@arguments) {
  animation: @arguments;
  -webkit-animation: @arguments;
}
.animation-playstate(@arguments) {
  animation-play-state: @arguments;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: @arguments;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from { top: 0; }
  to { top: -100%; }
}
.grid {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  .animation(marquee 70s infinite linear);
  &:hover {
    .animation-playstate(paused);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxgqQO?editors=1100 For older Firefoxes you could add the `-moz-` prefix, but current FF doesn't need it.

Comment: yeah but on association with the plugin jquery nested, it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay i found why. In the JS i add position absolute on the gird and now it works fine. You helped me thank you